# coordinate transform of TouchImageView in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coordinate-transformation

I want to know the final coordinate of predefined 2 points in TouchImageView.
1. If I just move the touchimageview, these codes are okay.
2. But if I scale or rotate touchimageview, the ptLeft and ptRight are not correct.

---

```
CGPoint ptLeft  = CGPointMake (100, 100);  
CGPoint ptRight = CGPointMake (200, 200); 
TouchImageView *touchView = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

....
....

/***** get the coordinate after TouchImageView has been scaled or rotated *****/
ptLeft  = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ptLeft, touchView.transform);  
ptRight  = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ptRight, touchView.transform);
```

---

Here is the touchimageview source code -
[TouchImageView source code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads164/sourcecode/macos/747251/MultiTouchDemo/Classes/TouchImageView.m__.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the UIView methods convertPoint:fromView: or convertPoint:toView:. Something like:

`ptLeft = [touchView convertPoint:ptLeft toView:[touchView superview]];`

(The latter argument should the view you want to have the point in. It looks like you're trying to get it in the superview, but you might want to use `self.view` or `nil` or something else instead.)

Comment: Hi Jesse, I have one more question, could you help ? In my program, I define a bound rectangle, CGRect rectBound = CGRectMake (10, 10, 300, 460); Now if the ptLeft or ptRight is moving out of the bound, I want to cancel the movement (or rotation) the the touchimageview. Do you know how to do it ? I

Comment: Perhaps you could create another question with more details? The most straight forward solution to me would be to set a BOOL indicating it's out of the bounds and stop rotating if that BOOL is set. You can use CGRectContainsPoint for the actual test.